# choosing network interface based on network purpose

Tags: linux, routing, ip, nfs

i have 3 NIC with ip address **10.10.10.2-eth0, 10.10.10.3-eth1, 10.10.10.4-eth2**

An NFS server with IP **10.10.10.5** and  want this NFS share to be accessed only through **10.10.10.3** that is through **eth1** 
and not through eth0 and eth2.

and for all other external communication it should use eth2 with ip 10.10.10.4

How can this be achieved,can any one please help me with this

Thanks

Comment: `1.` Clean up your question. You seem to be mixing the eth interfaces and ip addresses up. `2.` Why would you have 3 different interfaces connecting to the same layer 3 subnet? `3.` Can't you simply add a static route to the ip address of the NFS via the 10.10.10.3 interface?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by others you can add static routes

```
route add -host 10.10.10.5 dev eth1
```

and verfiy with

```
route -n
```